# Why is Font Awesome not working on my jekyll-built Github site?

Tags: jekyll, font-awesome, github-pages

I am using Jekyll to build my blog site, which is hosted by Github, and I am trying to incorporate font-awesome. The fa icons don't show up, and now my Github page is not updated with my latest blog post.

I've tried to link the font-awesome stylesheets to my css. I ended up using {% includes font-awesome.css %} in my stylesheet.css file, and I think that works fine.

In my navbar html, I've included the typical font-awesome i tag like so:

```
<li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/index.html"><i class='fa-home'></i> Home</a></li>
```

But the icons are not showing up on my Github site.

Also Github pages won't let me use the Jekyll-font-awesome plugin.
This was the plugin I used: https://gist.github.com/23maverick23/8532525
I added the plugin, **jekyll build** worked, but after I pushed the files to Github, I got this message from Github:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> The tag `icon` in `_includes/navbar.html,` is not a recognized Liquid
>   tag.
>   https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-unknown-tag-error

So I've removed the plugin and reverted to the recommended 'i' tags instead of the liquid tags.

When run **jekyll build** everything works fine. Then I commit my changes and push to github, and no errors.

When I run **jekyll serve** and view it locally, the icons show up and my latest blog post is visible.

But when I go to my Github page, my new blog post is not updating, and the font-awesome icons are not showing up.

Where did I go wrong? Why does Github Pages not like Font Awesome?

Comment: It's difficult to spot the bug without some code ? Did you have a repository url to give us ?

Comment: I believe that github pages does not support jekyll-font-awesome. These are the only ones they support: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages

Comment: I also advise to checkout _fontaweson Jekyll plugin_ here https://github.com/drewish/jekyll-font-awesome-sass

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just after opening of `<head>` tag in `default.html`, include the css for font awesome :

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, you should be using the icons as

```
<li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/index.html"><i class='fa fa-home'></i> Home</a></li>
```

If this does not work, then its because **github** doesnot build you pages from **markdown** if you have **plugins**.

If you need third party plugins then you should have two branches one for source and other for the **html build** by jekyll. You should push the builds in **master** branch and sources in any other branch.

You can configure these in **__config.yml** for source and destination and destination goes to master branch. You can view my [**__config.yml**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bistaumanga/bistaumanga.github.com/src/_config.yml) for reference. I push the sources in **src** branch and contents of destination in **master** branch. By pushing the html builds, github wouldn't try to build from sources.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I forgot the first 'fa' in 'fa fa-home'

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you have a FontAwesome Pro account. If you are a FontAwesome Pro account-holder, you need to register each domain you plan to use with your Pro CDN link.

For example, even if you include your Pro CDN link in your site's `<head>`, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha12345blahblahblahblahblah" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Your icons still may not show up. To resolve this, you need to sign in to your FontAwesome account and [register each new domain](https://fontawesome.com/account/services) to your CDN.

I am a Pro user (from the 2017 Kickstarter Campaign) and ran into this very problem. Registering my domain solved my problem promptly.