# How to use font awesome in Github pages using Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, font-awesome, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I created a Github pages site following this guide https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

So far, I have been able to display all information just by editing the index.md file and using the markdown. I want to insert font-awesome images.

What is the simplest way to do this? I tried searching how to use font-awesome on github pages but didn't find a tutorial that explains it (although I found questions that may indirectly answer it, but those pages from what I saw were how to build a Jekyll theme that uses font-awesome).

Edit: I saw this but I cannot find any html file. I only have `index.md` and `_config.yml`

Comment: Can you share your repository and url?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797627/why-is-font-awesome-not-working-on-my-jekyll-built-github-site

Comment: Which default theme are you using? If you go to the repo on github for the theme, there is likely a description of how to add custom styling.